# Virtual machine, mouse cursor only works within the box

Tags: virtualbox

I am experimenting with virtual box. One of my problems is that the mouse cursor only works within the box. How can I make it work both with the actual OS too and the virtual box at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right CTRL key to release the mouse and keyboard.
Documentation on the host key is [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp7689696). <-- Credit to [Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/3940/takkat) on the link

Install guest additions for transitions without manually releasing the keyboard/mouse.

Comment: right CTRL doesnt do anything. I really dont know why not. Is there a way to turn off the auto capture even before powering up the vbox?

Comment: For me, it doesn't auto-capture without guest additions.  It only captures if I click in the box.  Did you set a custom host key?  It should be displayed in the bottom right of the window.

Comment: ty - I may have customized this some time ago. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp7689696 for more

Answer (score 3):

To get your mouse cursor to work, you simply need to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the right side of the keyboard. If you don't want to keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to release the mouse cursor every time, simply install the VirtualBox Guest Additions by clicking on ***Devices*** > ***Install Guest Additions***. When you do this, you may need to mount the virtual cd-rom drive by using the following command:

`$ sudo mount /dev/scd0 /mnt/cdrom`

Then run the shell script to install the Guest Additions.

Comment: What shell script?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, do <kbd>right</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>. You will be out of virtual machine then right-click on mouse sign which is down-right side on virtual machine. Disable mouse integration.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In the VirtualBox Manager menu at the top of your screen, go to ***File> Preferences> Input***. Go to the ***Virtual Machine*** tab on the right. Look for ***Host Key Combination***, then look next to it under ***Shortcut*** and delete "Right CTRL". It should now say "None."

Click ***OK***.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I also could not replace "Right CTRL" after I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this on Ubuntu 18.04. I've found to make sure to not trap the mouse on VM boot up. Making sure to release it before mouse detection.

Also, I've set one of my VMs to Pointing Device: USB Multi-Touch Tablet and it makes my VM work with my USB mouse outside of the VM as long as I don't trap it on boot.

[image]